# Unite Gallery how to change grid position from right to bottom in resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this gallery [**unite gallery**](http://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=grid-right).

I need to *change grid position from right to the bottom* when is window smaller than `768` pixels

```
$(window).on('resize load', function () {
  let w = window.innerWidth;

  if(w <= 768){
    jQuery("#gallery").unitegallery({
      gallery_theme: "grid",
      theme_panel_position: "bottom"
    });
  }   else if(w > 768) {
    jQuery("#gallery").unitegallery({
      gallery_theme: "grid",
      theme_panel_position: "right"
    });
  }
```

But this code only change when window `onload` not in `onresize`

Comment: Did you try with just one event `resize`?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay yup

Comment: Then it does not work with `resize` only?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay How to fix it do you know ? =(

Comment: check the answer. Try it out. I hope it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code with my local setup and its working fine. Now you need to check if the JS plugin `unitegallery` returns JS object in the end. 
If it does so, then only we can bind further jquery to the element.

you can also try by getting the element object and store it in a variable like this,

```
var gallary = $('#gallery');
$(window).on('resize load', function () {
  let w = window.innerWidth;

  if(w <= 768){
    gallery.unitegallery({    // Notice the change here.
      gallery_theme: "grid",
      theme_panel_position: "bottom"
    });
  }   else if(w > 768) {
    gallery.unitegallery({    // Notice the change here.
      gallery_theme: "grid",
      theme_panel_position: "right"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It fixed the issue?